# Python + Eclipse+local GIT on Windows 10: Shoould I use the eclipse git plugin or use the GIT bash provided

Tags: git

Beginer with git so please forgive my ignorance.

I am trying to learn git and I am reading the ProGit book available for free on internet. as far as I can see the command line for this has many more options than the the GIT default plugin in Eclipse>

I need to learn as much GIT as to manage my local code end eventually later to push some of it on GitHub or elsewhere.

Having that said are there any pros and cons for using the command line only ?
To keep the things simpler should I stick with the plugin ?

Comment: Use whatever is more convenient for you. The command line will get you a good sense of what's really going on, but the plugin may be easier to use. For me, I will sometimes use a mix; adding/removing files, reviewing diffs, doing commits, rebases, etc are all on the command line. If I want to add only parts of a file (a la `git add -p`) I'll bring up some sort of diff tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly a matter of preference/personal taste.

The command line is more robust, powerful and gives deeper control in the way you want to handle Git. But requires advanced user skills that you can build up relatively easy. Using the command line also gives a nice idea of what is happening under the hood. You can easily become a professional user.

Plugins come handy as they have nice GUI/Integration and simple to use for regular stuff.

Usually, people use both, advanced operations via command line while simple operations using a plugin.

Tortorise Git or Sourcetree or Gitbash are different options.

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/ - Simple tutorial

Comment: thank you both for your replies, you are both basically recommending the same thing. I selected Roshan's answer because the link to the tutorial was very useful

Comment: Back to this: easier said than done from GUI. I created a basic project in PyDev and "shared" that by uploading in the local repository. Then I changed the only file in that project three times and committed each time. I can't figure out how to switch back to an older commit from GUI. CLI seems to be simple : git checkout 0d1d7fc32 where  0d1d7fc32 is a previous branch. How do I do that in Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend learning the basics of git (how a branch works, how to merge, how to pull and push code) from the GUI. Once you know the basics, learning which commands correspond to which GUI actions should be easy.

Purists will tell you that you will always have more control in the terminal. This is true, but no need to throw yourself into the deep end as a beginner. Get functional, then get fancy.

Most anything you can do in the command line, you'd be able to do in the GUI, but 
sometimes the command line is the only way to do whatever it is you need to do. This is especially true when you get into the more advanced parts of git: rebase, cherry-pick. It's a great skill to have, especially in cases where the GUI is not available, like when you are remote accessing a server.

The general question of GUI vs CLI is explored at length in [In the Beginning... Was the Command Line.](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~weis/info/commandline.html)